# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message coming

Tags: php, pdo

contact.php

```
<div class="block-content collapse in">
<div class="span12">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])=='Save changes'){
$row=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM contact_page WHERE addressline11=? LIMIT  
1");
$row->execute(array($_POST['addressline11']));

$q = $conn->prepare("UPDATE contact_page SET contact_content1=?,  
contact_content2=?, addressline11=?, addressline22=?, addressline33=?, 
tel_no1=?, website1=?, emailid1=?, WHERE id=?");
$q->execute(array($_POST['contact_content1'], $_POST['contact_content2'], 
$_POST['addressline11'], $_POST['addressline22'], $_POST['addressline33'], 
$_POST['tel_no1'], $_POST['website1'], $_POST['emailid1'], $_GET['id'] ));
echo '<div style="width:72%;"><p style="margin-top: 18px; margin-
left:20px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;vertical-align: top;padding: 
12px;">contact_content1:-</span> '.$_POST['contact_content1'].'
<p style="margin-top: 18px; margin-left:20px;"><span style="font-
weight:bold;vertical-align: top;padding: 12px;">contact_content2:-</span> 
'.$_POST['contact_content2'].'
<p style="margin-top: 18px; margin-left:20px;"><span style="font-\
weight:bold;vertical-align: top;padding: 12px;">Address Line 11:-</span> 
'.$_POST['addressline11'].'
<p style="margin-top: 18px; margin-left:20px;"><span style="font-
weight:bold;vertical-align: top;padding: 12px;">Address Line 22:-</span> 
'.$_POST['addressline22'].'
<p style="margin-top: 18px; margin-left:20px;"><span style="font-
weight:bold;vertical-align: top;padding: 12px;">Address Line 33:-</span> 
'.$_POST['addressline33'].'
<p style="margin-top: 18px; margin-left:20px;"><span style="font-
weight:bold;vertical-align: top;padding: 12px;">Telephone1 :-</span> 
'.$_POST['tel_no1'].'
<p style="margin-top: 18px; margin-left:20px;"><span style="font-
weight:bold;vertical-align: top;padding: 12px;">Website1:-</span> 
'.$_POST['website1'].'
<p style="margin-top: 18px; margin-left:20px;"> <span style="font-
weight:bold;vertical-align: top;padding: 12px;">Email Id1:-</span> 
'.$_POST['emailid1'];



echo '<p align="left" style="margin-top:10px; padding-left: 20px; 
color:blue; text-decoration:none; width:50%; font-weight:bold;"><a 
style="color:blue;" href="section2_list.php">Edit More Section 2</a></p>
</div>';

exit;

}

if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
foreach($conn->query("SELECT * FROM contact_page WHERE id='$_GET[id]' LIMIT 
1") as $stmt){
echo '<div>

<p>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="" autocomplete="off" method="post" 
id="footerform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                      <fieldset>
                                        <legend>Footer Section</legend>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                          <label class="control-label" 
for="contact_content1">Contact Content 1</label>
                                          <div class="controls">
                                            <input class="input-xlarge 
focused" id="contact_content1" name="contact_content1" type="text" required 
value="'.$stmt['contact_content1'].'">
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                          <label class="control-label" 
for="contact_content2">Contact Content 2</label>
                                          <div class="controls">
                                            <input class="input-xlarge 
focused" id="contact_content2" name="contact_content2" type="text" required 
value="'.$stmt['contact_content2'].'">
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                          <label class="control-label" 
for="addressline1">Address line 1</label>
                                          <div class="controls">
                                            <input class="input-xlarge 
focused" id="addressline1" name="addressline1" type="text" required 
value="'.$stmt['addressline11'].'">
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                          <label class="control-label" 
for="addressline2">Address line 2</label>
                                          <div class="controls">
                                            <input class="input-xlarge 
focused" id="addressline2" name="addressline2" type="text" required 
value="'.$stmt['addressline22'].'">
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                          <label class="control-label" 
for="addressline3">Address line 3</label>
                                          <div class="controls">
                                            <input class="input-xlarge 
focused" id="addressline3" name="addressline3" type="text" required 
value="'.$stmt['addressline33'].'">
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                          <label class="control-label" 
for="tel_no">Tel No.</label>
                                          <div class="controls">
                                            <input class="input-xlarge 
focused" id="tel_no" name="tel_no" type="text" required 
value="'.$stmt['tel_no1'].'">
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                          <label class="control-label" 
for="website">Website</label>
                                          <div class="controls">
                                            <input class="input-xlarge 
focused" id="website" name="website" type="text" required 
value="'.$stmt['website1'].'">
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                          <label class="control-label" 
for="emailid">Email</label>
                                          <div class="controls">
                                            <input class="input-xlarge 
focused" id="emailid" name="emailid" type="text" required 
value="'.$stmt['emailid1'].'">
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-actions">
                                          <input type="submit" name="submit" 
id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save changes" 
onclick="showoutput()">

                                        </div>
                                      </fieldset>
                                    </form>';  
}

}
?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /block -->
```

i m editing my form but the error is coming .

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near'WHERE id='2'' at line 1' in
>   G:\PleskVhosts\angelsoftweb.com\angelunitrax.com\admin\edit_contact_details.php:175
>   Stack trace:
>   `#0` G:\PleskVhosts\angelsoftweb.com\angelunitrax.com\admin\edit_contact_details.php(175):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>   `#1` {main} thrown in G:\PleskVhosts\angelsoftweb.com\angelunitrax.com\admin\edit_contact_details.php
>   on line 175

Comment: As per the error, it look like your `id` field is int and you are providing the varchar value to it. Remove the quotes `''` and it should be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra comma in the set clause:

`emailid1=?, WHERE id=?`

Proper query:

```
UPDATE contact_page SET contact_content1=?,  
contact_content2=?, addressline11=?, addressline22=?, addressline33=?, 
tel_no1=?, website1=?, emailid1=? WHERE id=?
```